# git push says rejected but goes through

Tags: git, github

I have a different problem than what generally caused by rewriting history at some point. Let me show you.

I'm on `ecoes-poc` branch and one commit ahead of its remote counterpart:

```
$ git log
917f264f  21 hours  xxx   (HEAD -> ecoes-poc) commit message
b2a6ce0e  2 days    xxx   (origin/ecoes-poc)  another commit message
```

At this point I did an amend to the last local commit, then tried to push:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.85 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (10/10), completed with 9 local objects.
To some-repo.git
   b2a6ce0e..aba1574b  ecoes-poc -> ecoes-poc
 ! [rejected]          master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'some-repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I thought someone else pushed to remote `ecoes-poc` before me, went to GitHub and surprised to see my rejected commit on top, and no one else had anything pushed. Came back to shell and a git log:

```
~ $ git log
a3bf26cc  21 hours  xxx   (HEAD -> ecoes-poc, origin/ecoes-poc) commit message
b2a6ce0e  2 days    xxx   another commit message
```

As shown, `origin/ecoes` is on the commit git just said it's rejected, and it's on GitHub as well.

So two questions I'm finding difficult to answer:

1. Why it's rejected in the first place?
2. How although git rejected the push, the commit ended up being on origin/ecoes branch, as well as on GitHub?

Comment: You pushed both `master` and `ecoes-poc`. Only `master` got rejected.

Comment: In addition to what @NilsWerner said: since your quote shows `git push` (not `git push --all` or some similar variant), you either configured `push.default` to `matching`, or you are using a pre-2.0 Git that defaults to `matching`. You probably should upgrade Git and/or configure `simple` (note that if your Git is truly ancient you may not *have* `simple`: it was added in Git 1.7.11).

Comment: Thank you guys, see my comment to Vampire as a lame excuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your error message:

```
To some-repo.git
   b2a6ce0e..aba1574b  ecoes-poc -> ecoes-poc
 ! [rejected]          master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

The push to `master` was rejected, the push to `ecoes-poc` went through.
It is not an all-or-nothing thing, but per pushed ref whether the push is rejected or not, at least in your case.

Hence `ecoes-poc` has your push while `master` does not have it.

What is pushed if you invoke `git push` without any additional parameters is defined by the config variable `push.default`. You can read about its values at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault. Obviously you have set it to `matching` which is the only option that will push more than the current branch, namely all name-matching branches. If not, then you might use a very old Git version where `matching` was the default behavior. You should probably update Git in that case.